# Unable to open gpio direction interface (Raspberry/Java)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am currently stuck with the following prob. The JAR & Pi4J Lib gets executed on a RasPi B+. I've been searching the web for hours without a result. Curiously looking forward to your reponses and support ;-)

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open GPIO    direction interface for pin [1]: No such file or directory

at com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil.export(Native Method)
at com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiGpioProvider.export(RaspiGpioProvider.java:108)
at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioPinImpl.export(GpioPinImpl.java:158)
at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionPin(GpioControllerImpl.java:517)
at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionDigitalOutputPin(GpioControllerImpl.java:669)
at com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionDigitalOutputPin(GpioControllerImpl.java:681)
at com.test.RemoteImpl.fahreVorwaerts(RemoteImpl.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.fahreVorwaerts(Unknown Source)
at com.client.RMIClient.main(RMIClient.java:19)

package com.test;
```

**The Code:**

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import com.interf.test.TestRemote;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalInput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinDirection;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinMode;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinPullResistance;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.trigger.GpioCallbackTrigger;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.trigger.GpioPulseStateTrigger;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.trigger.GpioSetStateTrigger;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.trigger.GpioSyncStateTrigger;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListener;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.PinEventType;

public class RemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements TestRemote {

    protected RemoteImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();

    }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean isloginvalid(String username) throws RemoteException {
        if (username.equals("test")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void fahreVorwaerts(int dauer) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("----- EXTCMD: VORWAERTS FAHREN "+"("+ dauer +"ms)" + "-----");
        // GPIO CODE SECTION BEGINS
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin_gpio01 = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "MyLED", PinState.LOW);
        pin_gpio01.pulse(dauer, true);
        System.out.println("----- INFO: VORWAERTS FAHREN ENDE -----");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Life could have been so much easier if I'd just had a look on the GPIO numbering. *There is no GPIO01!*

Anyway, now it works by choosing an existing GPIO. Cheers :-)

Answer (score -1):

## Raspberry pi 3 B GPIO

pi4j; GPIO Input  Error? "Unable to open GPIO edge interface for pin ??: No such file or directory"

-Solution-

1. Coding; `gpio.setShutdownOptions(true)` instead of `myButton.setShutdownoptions(true)` or `gpio.shutdown()`
2. Compile; Next, use the following command to compile this example program:
   `$ javac -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' -d . ListenGpioExample.java`

Execute the following command will run this example program:
`$ sudo java -classpath .:classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/'*' ListenGpioExample`

Answer (score -2):

Run with `sudo` command
`sudo java -jar yourjarname.jar`

Comment: Never run applications as root. Very bad practice.